# Power hundereds of LEDs using shift register

Tags: led, raspberry-pi, led-driver, shift-register, 74hc595

I have 400 LEDs I need to drive with a bank of 75hc595s. My problem is that the controller is a raspberry pi zero and the max input for it is 5 V at 1 A, however my LEDs are 3.0-3.2 V at 20 mA or 8 A. I need all the brightness I can get so I can’t use a current limiting resistor for that.

How can I power the LEDs using a different 3.3 V line like a power supply where I can give it more than 1 A like the raspberry pi?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: _”I can’t use a current limiting resistor for that”_ That’s not how LEDs work, regardless of your needs. You need to supply current limited voltage. Please draw a schematic of what you are proposing.

Comment: There are LED driver ICs of varying sophistication and capabilities. This is because large numbers of LEDs are difficult to manage. If you are excluding these ICs from consideration, say why. If you are not excluding them, what have you considered? (Many of them include shift registers so the 595's are not needed.) Also, keep in mind that if you multiplex, then the LED peak current requirements go up for a given brightness. Finally, why not do this in sections and use a separate, small, dedicated MCU for handling PWM brightness controls within its local section? Divide and conquer?

Comment: I would need much more information about your display before adding an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your current problem is to use a separate supply for your LEDs instead of using the RPI's onboard regulator.  Driving the LEDs depends on how they are configured.  10 strings of 40?  40 strings of 10?  Does each LED need individual control?  There are LED drivers that act like shift registers but also contain built-in current limiting circuits which are superior to plain series resistors.  If the 75HC595s can't be replaced, then use them to drive a logic-level MOSFET or NPN for each string of LEDs.  The maximum current that the 74HC595 will be able to handle is 70mA through the VCC or GND pins so even though the output current on an individual pin is 35mA, you won't be able to run more than three LEDs at a time on a single 74HC595.